# Is it possible to run a Windows executable in Mac OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, emulation

Is there some sort of emulator or software layer that will let me run Windows executables (exe) in Mac OS X 10.5?

I am not looking for Boot Camp or Parallels or any OS virtualization. I want something like WINE on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [ports of WINE for OS X](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/Installing) from other vendors (The WINE project does not make OS X binaries themselves), but remember, WINE Is **Not** an Emulator ;)

Did I mention how much I love recursive acronyms? :)

Answer (score 8):

You might also try [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxmac/), which is WINE with support. There's a free trial.

Comment: +1 You can use CrossOver to run executables, but the results might be less than spectacular; not everything runs all that great. For me, CrossOver was good enough though.