# How to run Windows-native MS Word on OS X?

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, wine

There is a Mac version of MS Office. But Word is much worse than the Windows version.

Is there any emulator and howto to run Windows-native versions of Word on OS X?

Comment: in short, not really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a Windows executable in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/92008/is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-executable-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: I used word in my OS X laptop daily for school. Haven't noticed anything worst than windows version. In fact, i quite like it more because of some of the things windows version doesn't have, like the note taking themes. I wonder what kind of problem you are having out of curiosity?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are 2 ways

1. Run Word under Wine wither the free version or Codeweavers' packaged up version - [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/tosf/)
2. Run Windows (you need a licensed copy) under a virtual machine e.g Virtual box (which is free), Parallels or VMWare Fusion

You could also use Bootcamp to run Windows instead of OSX

Comment: If you want to achieve this with the minimum amount of hassle, the VMware Fusion route is worth the money.

Answer (score 2):

There is [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/):

> CrossOver allows you to install many popular Windows applications on your Mac or Linux computer. You can think of it as an emulator, but it's different, because there's no Windows OS license required. Your applications integrate seamlessly in OS X or Linux; just click and run. No rebooting, no switching to a virtual machine, and no Windows Operating System license required!

I've tried it once, looks okay and does the job. It does cost a bit though.

As Randolf Richardson has mentioned, WINE is also possible on OS X, although [a bit harder to configure](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/Installing) if I recall correctly. But it's free and of course the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

WINE, which you smartly included as a tag, should do it for you:

MacOSX - The Official Wine Wiki
  http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX

WineHQ - Running Microsoft Word (various versions, lots of information)
  http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10

In Google Image Search, I just came across this image which appears to be of a very recent version of MS-Office, most likely running under WINE (at least the page it came from was explaining something about WINE), with support for another language (or a very different looking font):

[image]

Of course, there are alternatives such as OpenOffice.org (OOo) that can read/write MS-Office files directly, and since it's free it's definitely worth a try as well.  There are MacOS versions available for download for OOo:

OpenOffice.org (free and open source)
  http://www.openoffice.org/

Comment: That image is showing a Gnome desktop.

Comment: @slhck:  It sure resembles the MacOS GUI very closely though, but you're right (+1) -- this is the web page that image came from:  http://www.madurax86.com/rsinglishwine/

Comment: @Randolf I know, at first sight it does :)

Comment: @slhck:  Is that standard for Gnome right now (I like it)?  If so, then I think I'm going to have to take another look at that GUI in the near future.  =)

Comment: Office 2007 runs quite well under Gnome and WINE 1.3.21. I am using it since migrating from Windows to Ubuntu Lucid ;)

Comment: @Randolf The iconset is different and the dock is probably [one of those](http://www.linoob.com/2011/01/ultimate-docks-for-ubuntu/). Gnome 3 is a bit different, but I'd try it out nevertheless (Fedora or something)